# Feature Selection Using Bootstrap Resampling, LASSO and Stepwise Regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection, resampling

In [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33984349/), the authors perform radiomics feature selection for survival prediction by:

1. Bootstrap resampling the dataset x 1000
2. Fitting cross-validated LASSO models to each the resampled data sets
3. Retaining the 10 most common features with non-zero coefficients across all 1000 models
4. Fitting reverse stepwise regression using the ten selected features to the resampled datasets ( the same data sets as generated in step 1)
5. Choosing the final features based on the most common cox-regression model.

I would like to replicate this approach (albiet for logistic regression rather than cox-regression).

I am able to use the following R code to obtain the top K features from the Lasso models using the 'boot' library:

```
lasso_Select <- function(x, indices){ 
   x <- x[indices,]
   y <- x$Outcome
   x = subset(x, select = -Outcome)
   x2 <- as.matrix(x)
   fit <- glmnet(x2, y , family="binomial",alpha=1, standardize=TRUE)
   cv <- cv.glmnet(x2, y, family="binomial",alpha=1,  standardize=TRUE)
   fit <- glmnet(x2, y, family="binomial",alpha=1, lambda=cv$lambda.min,  standardize=TRUE)
     return(coef(fit)[,1])
   }

myBootstrap <- boot(scaled_train, lasso_Select, R = 1000, parallel = "multicore", ncpus=5)
```

However, I don't believe I can access the individual resampled datasets to then run the multiple logistic regression models and choose the most common.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Both `boot` and `glmnet` provide methods to dig into the low-level details of their subsamples.  See the manual page for `boot` and the (very well written) vignette for `glmnet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the manual page for `boot()` explains:

> For most of the boot methods the resampling is done in the master process, but not if `simple = TRUE` nor `sim = "parametric"`.

As you are not doing parametric bootstrapping and you don't need to specify `simple = TRUE`, the code displayed when you type `boot::boot` at the R prompt  shows how the resampled data indices are generated. The critical code is:

```
if (!simple) 
            i <- index.array(n, R, sim, strata, m, L, weights)
```

where `n` is the number of data rows, `R` is the number of bootstrap samples, and the other arguments are defined in the call to `boot()` and don't seem to apply to your situation. Typing `boot:::index.array` shows the code for that function, which in turn calls `boot:::ordinary.array` for your situation. In your situation, `i` is just a matrix showing which data rows to use for each bootstrap sample.

It should be reasonably straightforward to tweak the code for `boot()` to return that matrix of indices along with the other values the function normally returns.

An alternative might be to return `indices` directly in your `lasso_Select()` function, although I'm not sure how well the `boot()` function would handle that.